# filter items by value in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, filtering

I have a dict setup like so:

```
deck = [{
         'name': 'drew',
         'lvl': 23,
         'items': ['sword', 'axe', 'mana_potion']},
        {
         'name': 'john',
         'lvl': 23,
         'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion']}]
```

This is a basic example of what it looks like, I need a way to filter (copy only the {characters}) that match certain values, such as I want only characters that are level 23, or that are carrying a sword.

I was looking at doing something like this:

```
filtered = filter_deck(deck, 'mace')

def filter_deck(self, deck, filt):
        return [{k:v for (k,v) in deck.items() if filt in k}]
```

and return:

```
filtered = [{
             'name': 'john',
             'lvl': 23,
             'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion']}]
```

I am not sure how to filter either a specific item like k:v or k:[v1,v2,v3] when I do not know if it is a single value, or a list of values, or how to filter multiple values.

I am not sure how I can filter character's with multiple keys. Say that I want to sort out characters that are lvl 23, or have items['sword'] or items['mace']. How would I have it sort in a way `filter_cards(deck, ['lvl'=23, 'items'=['sword','mace'])`

So if any character is lvl 23, or carries a mace or a sword, they are on that list.

Comment: You want the whole dictionary , where the word is in the `items` value right?

Comment: Is it `filt in v` instead of `filt in k` in your dict comprehension?

Comment: For simple values you can try `in` keyword. If you want to know atleast one element in list A is present in list B. You can use sets. `A = ['mouse', 'mace']` and `B = ['sword', 'mace']` . You can check if A carries a mace or a sword by `set(A) & set(B)`. Also I think self in filtered deck function is not necessary. @Drew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `deck` is a list (of dictionaries) , it does not have `.items()` . so trying to do - `deck.items()` would fail.

Also the syntax -

```
filter_cards(deck, ['lvl'=23, 'items'=['sword','mace'])
```

is invalid , You should use a dictionary as the second element. Example -

```
filter_cards(deck, {'lvl':23, 'items':['sword','mace']})
```

You should use `filter()` built-in function, with a function that returns True, if the dictionary contains one of the values. Example -

```
def filter_func(dic, filterdic):
    for k,v in filterdic.items():
        if k == 'items':
            if any(elemv in dic[k] for elemv in v):
                return True
        elif v == dic[k]:
            return True
    return False

def filter_cards(deck, filterdic):
    return list(filter(lambda dic, filterdic=filterdic: filter_func(dic, filterdic) , deck))
```

---

Demo -

```
>>> deck = [{
...          'name': 'drew',
...          'lvl': 23,
...          'items': ['sword', 'axe', 'mana_potion']},{
...          'name': 'john',
...          'lvl': 23,
...          'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion']},{
...          'name': 'somethingelse',
...          'lvl': 10,
...          'items': ['health_potion']}]
>>>
>>>
>>> filter_cards(deck, {'lvl':23, 'items':['sword','mace']})
[{'lvl': 23, 'items': ['sword', 'axe', 'mana_potion'], 'name': 'drew'}, {'lvl': 23, 'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion'], 'name': 'john'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the standard `filter` and pass in the filter function, e.g:

```
filter(lambda x: 'mace' in x['items'], deck)
filter(lambda x: x['lvl'] == 23 or any(i in x['items'] for i in ['sword', 'mace']), deck)
```

Etc. These return filter generators so you if you want to print them out turn them into a list:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x['lvl'] == 23 or any(i in x['items'] for i in ['sword', 'mace']), deck))
[{'items': ['sword', 'axe', 'mana_potion'], 'lvl': 23, 'name': 'drew'},
 {'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion'], 'lvl': 23, 'name': 'john'}]
```

You could also break out the lambda into a standard function:

```
>>> def lvl_sword_mace(x):
...     return x['lvl'] == 23 or any(i in x['items'] for i in ['sword', 'mace'])
...
>>> list(filter(lvl_sword_mace, deck))
[{'items': ['sword', 'axe', 'mana_potion'], 'lvl': 23, 'name': 'drew'},
 {'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion'], 'lvl': 23, 'name': 'john'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to filter dict using list comprehension is by requesting the field that you want to filter against. `key in dictionary` is equivalent to `key in dictionary.keys()` in python2. The correct syntax is the following:

```
[card for card in deck if 'mace' in card['items']]
```

You can also use `filter`:

```
filter(lambda card: 'mace' in card['items'], deck)
```

If you want to filter against multiple values, you can chain tests using `and` and `or` to capture the subset your need:

```
[card for card in deck if 'mace' in card['items'] and card['lvl'] == 23]
```

If the filter gets bigger create a function.

In this case `filter` doesn't provide more value than list comprension. *List comprehension* are easier to read when they are short, more than their `filter` counter part. And for the  complex *filtering* cases, both requires a function to stay readable.

Answer (score 0):

`deck` isn't a dict, but a list of dicts, so I presume your search should return a list of the dicts that match your search criteria.

There are two cases to consider: the first is when you want to match a specific value for a particular key - which you will need for attributes like `lvl` and `name`. The second is where you are looking for a value in the list stored against an attribute. You'll need this, for example, to find out if a player is carrying a particular item.

It would make sense for you to actually *know* the difference between these - presumably `items` is always a list, and `lvl` is always an integer? - and you can register the types in a subsidiary dict like this:

```
is_list = {'name': False,
           'lvl': False,
           'items': True}
```

You could make the same decision dynamically if you had to by examining the `type()` of an item, but it's not very good practice to have variable data types as it complicates your logic somewhat. Since you add a `self` argument to your function I presume it's a method, but that's not really relevant to the question.

Given the presence of `is_list` your logic could define a `test_card` function that returns True if the card meets your criteria, and a `filter_deck` function that iterates over the deck returning only those cards that meet at least one of the criteria. The logic would then look something like this:

```
deck = [{
         'name': 'drew',
         'lvl': 23,
         'items': ['sword', 'axe', 'mana_potion']},
        {'name': 'john',
         'lvl': 23,
         'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion']},
        {'name': 'somethingelse',
         'lvl': 10,
          'items': ['health_potion']}]

is_list = {'name': False,
          'lvl': False,
          'items': True}

def test_card(card, name, values):
    if is_list[name]: # values is a list
        return any(value in card[name] for value in values)
    else:             # values is a single value
        return card[name] == values

def filter_deck(deck, **filters): # filters is a dict of keyword args
    r = []
    for d in deck:
        #print "Filtering", d, "on", filters
        if any(test_card(d, n, v) for n, v in filters.items()):
            r.append(d)
    return r

print filter_deck(deck, name="john")
print filter_deck(deck, name="drew", lvl=10)
```

which outputs

```
[{'lvl': 23, 'name': 'john', 'items': ['sword', 'mace', 'health_potion']}]
[{'lvl': 23, 'name': 'drew', 'items': ['sword', 'axe', 'mana_potion']}, {'lvl': 10, 'name': 'somethingelse', 'items': ['health_potion']}]
```

You could compress the logic more by using a list comprehension in `filter_deck` but that might make the program more difficult to read and understand. I always try for readability first.